# gdb Watchpoint not detecting change in variable

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

So I am running a program in GDB, and I set a watchpoint for a certain variable (an object pointer, to be specific), which exists at address 0x6030b0:

```
(gdb) wa (TNode<UCSDStudent> **)0x6030b0
Watchpoint 7: (TNode<UCSDStudent> **)0x6030b0
```

I know the value of the Pointer:

```
(gdb) p/x *((TNode<UCSDStudent> **)0x6030b0)
$5 = 0x603130
```

I have set a breakpoint at line 115, the end of my program. I then continue to this breakpoint:

```
(gdb) c  
Continuing.  

No more reverse-execution history.
main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd9a8) at Driver.c:115
115     ST.Write( cout << "\nFinal Symbol Table:\n" );
```

This implies that the value of the pointer did not change, because gdb did not stop at any watchpoint. I now print the value of the pointer:

```
(gdb) p/x *((TNode`<UCSDStudent>` **)0x6030b0)  
$6 = 0x0
```

However, the value of the pointer clearly did change. What can explain this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` command conceptually watches to see if an expression changes.  With `watch -location`, the command instead watches to see if a location changes (the difference being that if a variable goes out of scope, plain `watch` will update its idea of the expression, whereas `-location` will not -- you normally want `-location`).

Anyway, consider your expression:

```
(gdb) wa (TNode<UCSDStudent> **)0x6030b0
```

This is a constant.  So, it will never change.

You probably want:

```
(gdb) watch -location *(TNode<UCSDStudent> **)0x6030b0
```

Comment: i'ts not working for me, sometimes watchpoint breaks execution, sometimes it is not. I tried awa, wa, -location, address and variable name, it is work time to time( I can't understand what happen.